# Pandas groupby apply is very slow

Tags: python, pandas

```
grouped = data_v1.sort_values(by = "Strike_Price").groupby(['dateTime','close','Index','Expiry','group'])

def calc_summary(group):
    name = group.name
    if name[3] == "above":
        call_oi = group['Call_OI'].sum()
        call_vol = group['Call_Volume'].sum()
        put_oi = group['Put_OI'].sum()
        put_vol = group['Put_Volume'].sum()
        call_oi_1 = group.head(1)['Call_OI'].sum()
        call_vol_1 = group.head(1)['Call_Volume'].sum()
        put_oi_1 = group.head(1)['Put_OI'].sum()
        put_vol_1 = group.head(1)['Put_Volume'].sum()
   else:
        call_oi = group['Call_OI'].sum()
        call_vol = group['Call_Volume'].sum()
        put_oi = group['Put_OI'].sum()
        put_vol = group['Put_Volume'].sum()
        call_oi_1 = group.tail(1)['Call_OI'].sum()
        call_vol_1 = group.tail(1)['Call_Volume'].sum()
        put_oi_1 = group.tail(1)['Put_OI'].sum()
        put_vol_1 = group.tail(1)['Put_Volume'].sum()
   summary = pd.DataFrame([{'call_oi':call_oi,
                            'call_vol':call_vol,
                            'put_oi':put_oi,
                            'put_vol':put_vol,
                            'call_oi_1':call_oi_1,
                            'call_vol_1':call_vol_1,
                            'put_oi_1':put_oi_1,
                            'put_vol_1':put_vol_1,
   return summary

result = grouped.apply(calc_summary)
```

This above code takes too much time to run given the dataset is not even that big. Currently, it takes about 23 seconds in my system.
I tried swifter but that doesn't work with groupby objects.
What should I do to make my code faster?

Edit:
The data looks like this

```
  {'dateTime': {0: Timestamp('2023-02-06 09:21:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2023-02-06 09:21:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2023-02-06 09:21:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2023-02-06 09:21:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2023-02-06 09:21:00')},
 'close': {0: 17780.55, 1: 17780.55, 2: 17780.55, 3: 17780.55, 4: 17780.55},
 'Index': {0: 'NIFTY', 1: 'NIFTY', 2: 'NIFTY', 3: 'NIFTY', 4: 'NIFTY'},
 'Expiry': {0: '16FEB2023',
  1: '23FEB2023',
  2: '9FEB2023',
  3: '16FEB2023',
  4: '23FEB2023'},
 'Expiry_order': {0: 'week_2',
  1: 'week_3',
  2: 'week_1',
  3: 'week_2',
  4: 'week_3'},
 'group': {0: 'below', 1: 'below', 2: 'below', 3: 'below', 4: 'below'},
 'Call_OI': {0: nan, 1: 60.0, 2: 4.0, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'Put_OI': {0: 1364.0, 1: 11255.0, 2: 91059.0, 3: 343.0, 4: 153.0},
 'Call_Volume': {0: nan, 1: 3.0, 2: 2.0, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'Put_Volume': {0: 84.0, 1: 1246.0, 2: 5197.0, 3: 24.0, 4: 1.0},
 'Strike_Price': {0: 16100.0, 1: 16100.0, 2: 16100.0, 3: 16150.0, 4: 16150.0}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your sample data:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

csv = """
dateTime,close,Index,Expiry,Expiry_order,group,Call_OI,Put_OI,Call_Volume,Put_Volume,Strike_Price
2023-02-06 09:21:00,17780.55,NIFTY,16FEB2023,week_2,below,,1364.0,,84.0,16100.0
2023-02-06 09:21:00,17780.55,NIFTY,23FEB2023,week_3,below,60.0,11255.0,3.0,1246.0,16100.0
2023-02-06 09:21:00,17780.55,NIFTY,9FEB2023,week_1,below,4.0,91059.0,2.0,5197.0,16100.0
2023-02-06 09:21:00,17780.55,NIFTY,16FEB2023,week_2,below,,343.0,,24.0,16150.0
2023-02-06 09:21:00,17780.55,NIFTY,23FEB2023,week_3,below,,153.0,,1.0,16150.0
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv))
```

The output of your `calc_summary` function:

```
>>> df.sort_values(by='Strike_Price').groupby(['dateTime', 'close', 'Index', 'Expiry', 'group']).apply(calc_summary)
                                                      call_oi  call_vol   put_oi  put_vol  call_oi_1  call_vol_1  put_oi_1  put_vol_1
dateTime            close    Index Expiry    group                                                                                   
2023-02-06 09:21:00 17780.55 NIFTY 16FEB2023 below 0      0.0       0.0   1707.0    108.0        0.0         0.0     343.0       24.0
                                   23FEB2023 below 0     60.0       3.0  11408.0   1247.0        0.0         0.0     153.0        1.0
                                   9FEB2023  below 0      4.0       2.0  91059.0   5197.0        4.0         2.0   91059.0     5197.0
```

---

#### [`.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html)

You're performing an aggregation where you conditionally want the head/tail depending on the value of the `group` column.

You could aggregate both values instead and then do the filtering afterwards.

This allows you to use `.agg()` directly.

We can use `first` and `last` aggregations for `head`/`tail` but must first `fillna(0)` as they handle `NaN` values differently.

```
summary = (
   df.fillna(0) # needed for first/last as they ignore NaN
     .sort_values(by='Strike_Price')   
     .groupby(['dateTime', 'close', 'Index', 'Expiry', 'group'])
     [['Call_OI', 'Call_Volume', 'Put_OI', 'Put_Volume']]
     .agg(['first', 'last', 'sum'])
     .reset_index()
)
```

Which produces a multi-indexed column structure like:

```
              dateTime     close  Index     Expiry  group Call_OI            Call_Volume             Put_OI                   Put_Volume                
                                                            first last   sum       first last  sum    first     last      sum      first    last     sum
0  2023-02-06 09:21:00  17780.55  NIFTY  16FEB2023  below     0.0  0.0   0.0         0.0  0.0  0.0   1364.0    343.0   1707.0       84.0    24.0   108.0
1  2023-02-06 09:21:00  17780.55  NIFTY  23FEB2023  below    60.0  0.0  60.0         3.0  0.0  3.0  11255.0    153.0  11408.0     1246.0     1.0  1247.0
2  2023-02-06 09:21:00  17780.55  NIFTY   9FEB2023  below     4.0  4.0   4.0         2.0  2.0  2.0  91059.0  91059.0  91059.0     5197.0  5197.0  5197.0
```

To say you want the `last` values when `group != "above"` you can:

```
>>> below = summary.loc[summary['group'] != 'above', summary.columns.get_level_values(1) != 'first']
>>> below
              dateTime     close  Index     Expiry  group Call_OI       Call_Volume        Put_OI          Put_Volume        
                                                             last   sum        last  sum     last      sum       last     sum
0  2023-02-06 09:21:00  17780.55  NIFTY  16FEB2023  below     0.0   0.0         0.0  0.0    343.0   1707.0       24.0   108.0
1  2023-02-06 09:21:00  17780.55  NIFTY  23FEB2023  below     0.0  60.0         0.0  3.0    153.0  11408.0        1.0  1247.0
2  2023-02-06 09:21:00  17780.55  NIFTY   9FEB2023  below     4.0   4.0         2.0  2.0  91059.0  91059.0     5197.0  5197.0
```

To flatten the column structure similar to your functions output you can:

```
>>> below.columns = [left.lower() + ('' if right in {'', 'sum'} else '_1') for left, right in below.columns]
>>> below
              datetime     close  index     expiry  group  call_oi_1  call_oi  call_volume_1  call_volume  put_oi_1   put_oi  put_volume_1  put_volume
0  2023-02-06 09:21:00  17780.55  NIFTY  16FEB2023  below        0.0      0.0            0.0          0.0     343.0   1707.0          24.0       108.0
1  2023-02-06 09:21:00  17780.55  NIFTY  23FEB2023  below        0.0     60.0            0.0          3.0     153.0  11408.0           1.0      1247.0
2  2023-02-06 09:21:00  17780.55  NIFTY   9FEB2023  below        4.0      4.0            2.0          2.0   91059.0  91059.0        5197.0      5197.0
```

There are no examples of `above` in your data - but you could do the same for those rows using `== 'above'` and `!= 'last'` and concat both sets of rows into a single dataframe.

### Polars

---

You may also wish to compare how the dataset performs with [polars.](http://pypi.org/project/polars)

One possible approach which generates the same output:

```
import io
import polars as pl

df = pl.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv))

columns = ["Call_OI", "Call_Volume", "Put_OI", "Put_Volume"]

(
   df
   .sort("Strike_Price")
   .groupby(["dateTime", "close", "Index", "Expiry", "group"], maintain_order=True)
   .agg([
      pl.col(columns).sum(),
      pl.when(pl.col("group").first() == "above")
        .then(pl.col(columns).first())
        .otherwise(pl.col(columns).last())
      .suffix("_1")
   ])
   .fill_null(0)
)
```

```
shape: (3, 13)
┌─────────────────────┬──────────┬───────┬───────────┬───────┬─────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬────────────┬───────────┬───────────────┬──────────┬──────────────┐
│ dateTime            | close    | Index | Expiry    | group | Call_OI | Call_Volume | Put_OI  | Put_Volume | Call_OI_1 | Call_Volume_1 | Put_OI_1 | Put_Volume_1 │
│ ---                 | ---      | ---   | ---       | ---   | ---     | ---         | ---     | ---        | ---       | ---           | ---      | ---          │
│ str                 | f64      | str   | str       | str   | f64     | f64         | f64     | f64        | f64       | f64           | f64      | f64          │
╞═════════════════════╪══════════╪═══════╪═══════════╪═══════╪═════════╪═════════════╪═════════╪════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════════╪══════════╪══════════════╡
│ 2023-02-06 09:21:00 | 17780.55 | NIFTY | 16FEB2023 | below | 0.0     | 0.0         | 1707.0  | 108.0      | 0.0       | 0.0           | 343.0    | 24.0         │
│ 2023-02-06 09:21:00 | 17780.55 | NIFTY | 23FEB2023 | below | 60.0    | 3.0         | 11408.0 | 1247.0     | 0.0       | 0.0           | 153.0    | 1.0          │
│ 2023-02-06 09:21:00 | 17780.55 | NIFTY | 9FEB2023  | below | 4.0     | 2.0         | 91059.0 | 5197.0     | 4.0       | 2.0           | 91059.0  | 5197.0       │
└─────────────────────┴──────────┴───────┴───────────┴───────┴─────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴────────────┴───────────┴───────────────┴──────────┴──────────────┘
```

Comment: The variable 'group' is just one particular column. What I want is something of the format, "for each Index, for each time (data is in 1 minute interval), for each closing price, what is the behaviour of market above the closing price and below the closing price. Instead of one strike price above closing I can also take 3 strike prices. But the code itself is very slow to run as it is running as if a for loop is going over each group. How to do parallelism so the code uses different core to calculate groupwise simultaneously?

Comment: In my example it is a single column - yes. You can replace `.groupby("group", as_index=False)` in my example with your `.groupby(['dateTime','close','Index','Expiry','group'], as_index=False)`. You may also want to see how fast [polars](https://pypi.org/project/polars/) is with your data.

Comment: With as_index = False, the code takes about the same time, 22.4 seconds. I am trying polaris. I'll let you know.

Comment: Are you also using the `.sum().merge()` approach? If the data is public - I can run some local testing if you like.

Comment: Not sure about .sum().merge() approach. The data I have is supposed to be public but I have scraped the data through some sites. So not sure is that should be shared.

Comment: I am trying the dask approach as I could not implement polaris. Polaris doesnt have groupby then apply it seems like. In dask I am just getting meta error. :(

Comment: The code I've given here should be used instead of `.groupby().apply()` - just replace `groups = df.groupby("group", as_index=False)` with `groups = df.groupby(['dateTime','close','Index','Expiry','group'], as_index=False)` - it should be equivalent to your function. If you can provide even a few rows of data as an example - it would be easier to help. Polars does have `.groupby().apply()` - but the whole point is not to use `.apply()` at all as it's not needed in this case (and it's "slow").

Comment: You'll probably have to edit your question and put the data example in there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251714/discussion-between-rio-and-jqurious).